# Map not found in RxJS in angular2

Tags: angular, rxjs

Error:  Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable'.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
declare var $: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  testDetails:any;
  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.display();
}
display() {
  this.getTestDetails().subscribe(data => {
      this.testDetails = data;
      console.log((this.testDetails));
  });

}
getTestDetails() {
  return this.http.get('https://randomuser.me/api/')
      .map(res => res.json());
}
  title = 'ecom-project';

}
```

Same Code is running other PC but in my PC i am facing error. What is missing my code setup.

Answer (score 5):

What version of RXJS Are you using? if the latest, then it should be:

```
import { map } from "rxjs/operators";
```

Then you need to do

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'; (NOT @angular/http)

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

....this.http.get().pipe(map())
```

Also, if you are using the latest verison of the HttpClient, then you don't even need to map to JSON, it's done automatically

Comment: Thank you, now getting response.

Comment: But why i can't use map function and why using pipe. I am using angular6

Comment: Because it was changed in the latest RxJS update. That USED to work, but no more :(